# Visual Studio 2005 Express with Microsoft Platform SDK

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I am facing a problem with integrating Microsoft Platform SDK with Visual Studio 2005 Express, now it looks like it does not include it with the default installation.

So I installed Microsoft Platform SDK for Windows 2003 (as reccomended by http://www.zedwood.com/article/134/visual-studio-express-2005-and-the-platform-sdk) and carried out accordingly) - Althogh I could not find C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\VCProjectDefaultscorewin_express.vsprops, so I could not comment out what he reccomended.

But the problem I face is that I have compiling from command line cl.exe, and it does not seem to be finding io.h (which I understand is part of the Microsoft Platform SDK) and doesn't seem to be included in Visual Studio 2005 Express.

How would I include this (io.h) file when compiling? (I know you can add INCLUDE values in the IDE, but as it's command line I don't think it will work - I have tried)

Note: Unfortunately I am restricted in using Visual Studio 2005 express, so I can't upgrade etc.

This has been driving me mad, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have also executed vcvars, but still no luck

Comment: Any technical reason to stay with VS2005 Express?

Comment: I am assuming you are using Visual C++ 2005 Express.  Have you tried #include <iostream> instead of the deprecated <io.h> ?

Comment: Hi, thanks I have actually got it working partially, I added the line "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Include\crt" into the INCLUDES section of vsvars32.bat and it has found it, but now its missing "basetsd.h".. More searching. I am sticking with VS 2005 as the program was initally built using VS 2005 and I have little experience with MS development tools, I don't seem to get along with them..

Answer (score 1):

`io.h` should be in the C runtime include directory, not the SDK's.  Something like:

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\include\io.h

If you're running builds from the command line make sure the environment is set correctly.  One way to do that is to run the `\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat` script which should have been installed by VC2005 Express (there should be a shortcut to it on the start menu).

Comment: Thanks for all feedback, got it working..

edit C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat

and add the line: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Include;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\Include\crt;
into the "@set INCLUDE=" section!


cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools
vsvars32.bat

Comment: I've just installed VC 2005 Express and verified that `io.h` is in the normal `VC\include` directory. You may want to reinstall - who knows what other damage there might be to the existing installation?